# I want to collect the common elements in two different arraylist

Tags: arrays

```
ArrayList1 = [a,b,c,d]
ArrayList1 = [d,c,e,f,g]
```

I would like to have result as

```
ArrayListFinal = [c,d]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Could you show us why your code does not work?

Comment: You have two `ArrayList1`

Answer (score 1):

try this...........

```
for(int i =0;i<list1.size();i++){
    for(int j=0;j<list2.size();j++){
        if(list.get(j).equals(list2.get(i))){
            listfinal.add(list.get(i));
        }
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<listfinal.size();i++){
    System.out.println(list1.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is to find the **intersection** (denoted as ∩) of two array A and B .

Suppose the arrays are unsorted. The simplest way is to compare the elements one by one, like this:

```
function getIntersect(arr1, arr2) {
    var temp = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
        for(var k = 0; k < arr2.length; k++){
            if(arr1[i] == arr2[k]){
                temp.push( arr1[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

But if the arr2 is much shorter than arr1, you may using a hash table to speed up:

```
function getIntersect(arr1, arr2) {
    var r = [], o = {}, l = arr2.length, i, v;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        o[arr2[i]] = true;
    }
    l = arr1.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        v = arr1[i];
        if (v in o) {
            r.push(v);
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```